# Change text of "Return" keyboard button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

How can I change the standard text of the "Return" button to something else?

I want it to be "Add".

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489879/ios-keyboard-with-go-button-instead-of-return

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can change "Return" into only one of these predefined labels with the `returnKeyType` property:

- Return (default)
- Go
- Google
- Join
- Next
- Route
- Search
- Send
- Yahoo
- Done
- Emergency Call
- Continue (as of iOS 9)

So maybe you should choose "Next" if a data entry kind of activity is what you're after.

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType).

Comment: From now on I'm using Yahoo as the default action button text in my iOS apps.

Comment: That's weird nobody thinks about "Save" label.

Comment: iOS 9 supports UIReturnKeyType Send

Comment: It's supported since iOS 2.0, actually.

Comment: Isn't it kind of ridiculous that these options have not changed in 2018? I wanted to set my return label to "Ask". Oh well I guess Send will have to suffice.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this simple way:
`[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext]; or [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];` instead of "Add" button.

Other, you create a programmatically keyboard with buttons which you want.

Answer (score 3):

iOS 9 now supports Send button. This is the following swift code

```
self.liveChatMessage.returnKeyType = .Send
```

Objective C:

```
[self.liveChatMessage setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyTypeSend];
```