# iOS keyboard with "Go" button instead of return

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to use the keyboard with "Go" key instead of the "Return" key like when you are accessing login fields in Safari? I'm guessing this should be something trivial but my searches aren't turning up anything. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

For a `UITextField` or editable `UITextView`:

```
[myTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
```

You can also configure this in Interface Builder, under **Text Input Traits** for your text field/view:

[image]

Comment: or in IB choose Return Key "Go"

Comment: Thanks. I knew the answer was something this simple, but it looks like my google skills fail me today. Accepting answer in 8 mins. :)

Comment: This answer was useful to me, but I was also looking for the callback function from the "Go" button, which I found is:

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Customer code
    return YES;
}

You will need to send the UITextField delegate to your view controller for that to work.

Comment: @BoltClock : Can we add custom text like "Here we go!" on return button?

Answer (score 3):

In Xamarin.iOS or Monotouch is:

```
myTextField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Go;
```

Possible values are:

```
   Default
   Go
   Google
   Join
   Next
   Route
   Search
   Send
   Yahoo
   Done
   EmergencyCall
   Continue
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myTextField.returnKeyType =  UIReturnKeyType.Go
```

Other options for return key name can be found at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple way: `[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];` instead of "Add" button.

Other, you create a programmatically keyboard with buttons which you want.