# How do I change the text on the Keyboard Return key based on which control is active?

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

I have figured out how to manipulate what the Return key does on the popup keyboard via the KeyDown event, but I would like to edit the label on this key, too. For example, working with an app on a log-on page:

I would ideally like to have that the Return key of the user-name text box say "Next," and then for the password text box, the Return key will say "Log in." Pressing it will log them in instead of just dismissing the keyboard, so they don't have to press the log-in button on the form.

Comment: Possibly relevant, depending on what Delphi exposes of the native UI capabilities: [iOS keyboard with “Go” button instead of return](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4489879/33732)

Comment: I'm familiar with XCode and how to do this via XCode. Doesn't really apply in Delphi. Thank you though.

Comment: The answer there also shows calling `setReturnKeyType` on the edit control. But again, I don't know whether Delphi exposes that ability.

Comment: No, they don't unfortunately.