# Keyboard with “Go” button instead of return in Unity using the new 4.6 ui

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do [this - iOS keyboard with “Go” button instead of return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489879/ios-keyboard-with-go-button-instead-of-return), but from Unity using the new 4.6 ui, so I am trying to pass as parameter an InputField to the external method that is expecting a UITextField. So far this doesn't seem possible.
Is there another way to perform this in Unity?

Comment: I'm not sure but check "Content Type" in properties tab of InputField.

Comment: Hello, Yeah i tested that without success Thanks!