# regarding keyboard next and go in ios platform using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false); and cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); 
what happens in each case??i tried it but not understood ...can any one help ??

Answer (score 0):

If You use hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false); then there will be accessory bar above your virtual keyboard with option .and If you are using cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); It will hide that accessory bar.

[image]

For moving to next input field use this directive

```
app.directive('focus', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function($scope,elem,attrs) {
  console.log(elem);
   elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      elem[0].nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
    });
  }
 }
 });
```

use this directive in your input field like this

```
<input type="text" id="" ng-model="" focus/>
```

thanks

Comment: then what is the solution for When we click on the input text box we need to show next button instead of the Go button.in android and ios platforms

Comment: in ionic , can tell me for going the cursor to next input field when user clicks enter?@Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/N9T9e/ , will help you acheive what you want :)

Comment: i needed without using jquery?@Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: What is happening now , when you click enter ? Is it submitting the form ?

Comment: i needed it with javascript and angularjs  @Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: i have 3 textfields when on entering 1st textfield then hit enter it should go to 2nd textfield afterthat to 3rd textfield..after filling 3rd textfield it is submitting thats fine.. problem with 1st and 2nd need to go next on hit of enter @Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: what is focus function in the code ?? @Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: This is what moving cursor from one input field to another by focusing it

Comment: but it is showing focus not defined?@Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: Created a jsfiddle for you , http://jsfiddle.net/kushcrimson/e4nh2wpm/2/

Comment: the follwing is the error...Cannot read property 'focus' of null @Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: show me your console.log(elem) ... that will help find out. Also what happens if you use next().focus(); instead of nextElementSibling ?

Comment: now when i put next().focus(); instead of nextElementSibiling it is not show ing error..

Comment: create a fiddle and share link ;(

Comment: What is the proper way to get the "next" button to display on the ios keyboard rather than "Go" @ Ujjwal kaushik

Comment: not sure what are you asking , Can you refer me to any scrrenshot that would be nice

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1240178/6982444/1937b092-d9cf-11e4-9a87-50ae176858a1.png

Comment: open that image in place of Go key i needed Next key for my application???

Comment: All i know about this is you can change using native code , not sure about ionic .. but take a look at this https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinputtraits#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489879/ios-keyboard-with-go-button-instead-of-return .. maybe it will help