# Simulate "Go", "Next" button press on iOS onscreen keyboard for xcode test

Tags: ios, xcode

Writing some unit tests with `XCUIApplication`.

We have an accessibility test to ensure that clicking the "Go" button on the onscreen keyboard logs a user in if they have entered a valid username and password.

I know that features like `typeText("\r")` can simulate a keyboard press for `Return`, but I'm not sure if that's a reasonable substitute for "Go".

Additionally, we need to test in clicking "Next" on the username field takes you to the password field below it.

Right now we are doing these tests manually on physical devices, but would love to automate them.

Is there a way to explicitly tell xcode to simulate "Go" and/or "Next" clicks from the iOS onscreen keyboard?

i.e. `XCUIApplication().keypress("iOSGO")` or something along those lines.

-or-

Do those buttons just transmit `Return` and `Tab` keypress events behind the scenes, and therefore `typeText("\r")` and `typeText("\t")` work as acceptable substitutes.

Answer (score 1):

Those buttons are configurable on the keyboard to show different displays instead of "Return".

Check [iOS keyboard with "Go" button instead of return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489879/ios-keyboard-with-go-button-instead-of-return) for more information.

Your second option is solid, but you should use just "/r" and shouldn't need "/t"

Comment: Only concern is that "Next" and "Go" are different actions entirely. One should take you from the first text box to the second, and the other should attempt to log you in. Link is helpful, but the core of the question comes down to: Does ("Go" == "\r") and ("Next" == "\t")