# Change label/text/font of return in keyboard as a submit button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keyboard, uibutton

Can anybody suggest me how to change label/text/font of "Return" in keyboard as "Submit" ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976950/change-text-of-return-keyboard-button

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What is the "font" part of the question? It sounds like you just want to change the label (to a value that isn't supported). I think you mean to ask "how to change the label of the Return key to Submit".

Comment: @Angel That's better. There is no way to change the Return key to Submit. See the docs for `UIReturnKeyType` for the possible values. `Send` is probably the closest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change "Return" into only one of these predefined labels with the **returnKeyType** property:

Return (default)

Go

Google

Join

Next

Route

Search

Send

Yahoo

Done

Emergency Call

**But there is No way to change the FONT of the Text**

I took this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/977012/64976, by [macbirdie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5049/macbirdie)

Comment: It's very bad form to copy the text of an answer already referenced in a comment here and post it as your own answer. And the reference to *font* was removed before you posted.

Comment: But You didn't Posted it as Answer...

Comment: Because I don't take credit for other people's answers. You are taking credit for someone else's answer to another question.

Answer (score -1):

you will find return key property in attribute inspector in xib  if you have taken textfied or textview in xib,where you can set "Submit" in place of "Return".

Comment: But there is no any submit button. i mean in xib @Return key there is only limited options like "Go, Done, Return, Yahoo, Google, Join, Next, Route , Search, Send, Emergency call"

Comment: what you have taken in xib?textfield or textview?

Comment: i m taking textfield in xib