# iOS Keyboard shows SAVE

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a `UITextField` and I would like to have a `UIkeyBoard` that shows 'SAVE'.

How can I make the keyboard show 'SAVE' button?
I am aware of options that can be configured like Default, GO, DONE, NEXT

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976950/change-text-of-return-keyboard-button

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the text of `UIKeyBoard`'s button manually.

Here is a link of [all the return keys that you can use instead](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIReturnKeyType), Apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the keyboard change button to `SAVE`.

You can change "Return" into any one of those allowed in apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html)