# keeping iphone keyboard on screen and change its enter button name

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

i want to show my keyboard on screen , whenever a view is shown i.e my login screen..
and i also want to change the name of enter button to Login button.

please help

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976950/change-text-of-return-keyboard-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the return key value, change the `UIReturnKeyType` enum [(UITextInputTraits)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIReturnKeyType).

If you want the keyboard to show on the screen when it loads, you need to hook up your UITextField to the delegate and include UITextFieldDelegate in your header file. (That is assuming you are using a UITextField.)

Then call:
`[textField becomeFirstResponder]`
in your viewWillAppear method to give focus to the UITextField which then raises the keyboard.