# Navigate to a new page when search bar is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react native element search bar. By default when user clicks on the search bar, a keyboard with "Return" key in lower right corner is shown. How can I change this to display keyboard with "Search" key on lower right corner?

Also when I click on the return key, I want a function to be called (Like: this.props.navigation.navigate("abc")). I do not want to use onBlur={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("abc")} as the user might just click else where on the screen and still this function would be called.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text of "Return" keyboard button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976950/change-text-of-return-keyboard-button)

Comment: @gravity The link you had in comment does not talk about how this could be done in react native when using react-native-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs, the `react-native-elements` [SearchBar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html)

*inherits all React Native Elements [`Input`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html#props) props, which means all native [`TextInput`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onendediting) props that come with a standard React Native TextInput element*

therefore you can use:

- [`onSubmitEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting)
- [`returnKeyType`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#returnkeytype)

  ```
  <SearchBar
   ...
   onSubmitEditing={this.navigate} // <== Your Navigation handler
   returnKeyType='search' />
  ```